# Fast Corner Detection in Metal

Tags: ios, metal, compute-shader, corner-detection

I am considering how one might implement a fast corner detection in metal. The input to the kernel function is a texture where the corners are to be detected, and the result from all kernel functions is to be the list of all detected corners. So each kernel function might add a corner or it might not. My question is how do we accumulate all the discovered corners in a device buffer.  In worse case I would allocate a seperate index to each kernel function where it should write a boolean, but it will be a very sparse array and unnecessarily huge too.  So I would prefer not to pre assign indices, but rather that a kernel function somehow gets the next free index to use if it detects a corner.  So I thought I should use atomic_compare_exchange on an integer index variable to achieve this. So the next_free_index is a shared variable that gets incremented thread safe for every corner found.  The downside is that the GPU threads might likely stall while accessing this variable which would slow the compute. I would like to know if this would be a reasonable approach to do this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is largely the intended use case for atomics in shaders. The atomic operations should be lock free, although there is presumably some cache and memory channel coordination mechanism that makes it slower than a normal increment or whatever. So, it may have some performance impact, but not too bad. Also, if very few invocations of the kernel function actually find corners ("very sparse"), then contention will be low. And, of course, if there's no other way to do it, then performance be damned. ;)

Comment: Thanks :)  I would like the perf to be a multiple higher than there is on the CPU despite the contention.  I was wondering if the threads on the later GPUs within a thread group operate in lockstep (all threads are on the same instruction, and stall on conditionals (if-else divergence) till other threads are caught up). It they do it adds to the odds that they might be in contention at the same time?

Comment: I don't know enough about the inner workings of GPUs to be able to tell about the lockstep notion, but are you expecting corners to be detected right near each other? If not, then the threadgroup is no more likely to contend over the atomic than any other threads. I.e. only one thread in the group (or so) is likely to be operating on the atomic at a time. In any case, I expect you'll get orders of magnitude better performance than you would using the CPU!

Comment: Did some more research. The lockstep is restricted to a warp - which is 16 or 32 threads, so as you suspected unlikely for there to be contention.  The warp is SIMD, so it optimizes on instruction fetch cycle across its threads.